# changing state inside map return causes a 'Too many re-renders' error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

white trying to add values to the array in the setPositions call, that line causes Too many re-renders error

> ```
> export default function () {
>   const colors: string[] = ['#b22828', '#42853a', '#bbb', '#378e91', '#bb32b3'];
>   const [positions, setPositions] = useState<Position[]>([]);
>
>   return (
>       <ChakraProvider>
>           {[1, 2, 3].map((element, index) => {
>               let top: number = RandomPicker(10, 800);
>               let left: number = RandomPicker(15, 1500); 
>               //the next line causes the error
>               setPositions([new Position(top, left), ...positions]);
>               console.log(positions);
>               let color: string = colors[RandomPicker(0, colors.length)].toString();
>               return (
>                   <Clickable
>                       key={index}
>                       top={top.toString() + 'px'}
>                       left={left.toString() + 'px'}
>                       color={color}
>                   />
>               );
>           })}
>       </ChakraProvider>
>   );
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You are enqueueing state updates in the render function return. In the case of function components the ***entire*** component function body ***is*** the render function. These enqueued state updates are an unintentional/unexpected side-effect in what should be considered a pure function, the render looping issue is created.

Use an `useEffect` hook to issue side-effects.

From what I can tell you are wanting to generate 3 random positions and then map them to `Clickable` components.

```
export default function () {
  const colors: string[] = ['#b22828', '#42853a', '#bbb', '#378e91', '#bb32b3'];
  const [positions, setPositions] = useState<Position[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPositions([1, 2, 3].map(() => 
      new Position(RandomPicker(10, 800), RandomPicker(15, 1500))
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      {positions.map((element, index) => {
        const color: string = colors[RandomPicker(0, colors.length)];
        return (
          <Clickable
            key={index}
            top={top.toString() + 'px'}
            left={left.toString() + 'px'}
            color={color}
          />
        );
      })}
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

Or just map the initial state directly.

```
export default function () {
  const colors: string[] = ['#b22828', '#42853a', '#bbb', '#378e91', '#bb32b3'];
  const [positions, setPositions] = useState<Position[]>([1, 2, 3].map(
    () => new Position(RandomPicker(10, 800), RandomPicker(15, 1500))
  );

  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      {positions.map((element, index) => {
        const color: string = colors[RandomPicker(0, colors.length)];
        return (
          <Clickable
            key={index}
            top={top.toString() + 'px'}
            left={left.toString() + 'px'}
            color={color}
          />
        );
      })}
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```